# How to check order-status of each items individually particular order in Magento-2.1.12?

Tags: magento2.1

Suppose I have one order with multiple items. How to check order-status of each item individually particular order in Magento-2.1.12?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? How has it failed?

Comment: I want to check order-status of each item of particular order.But in magento2.1,it show order-status on order not for items.

Comment: Suppose I have 2 items in one order,one of them is ready to deliver,but second is take some day more.How it will maintain in magento2?

Comment: Please include some code that demonstrates what you've tried and researched.

Comment: A good question should contain examples of what you've tried to make it easier to help you solving your problem. You might also want to take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In Myntra,Flipkart etc. every website is is provide order-status of each item of particular order.This is possible in magento 2.1?